# Delete multiple rows from multiple CSV files with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm python beginner and currently trying to complete exercise where I permanently remove multiple rows from multiple CSV files in one directory. So far I've managed to remove first 4 rows with the following code:

```
import glob
myfiles = glob.glob('/path/to/my/files/*.csv')

for file in myfiles:
    lines = open(file).readlines()
    open(file, 'w').writelines(lines[4:])
```

How can I remove first 4 rows, skip the 5th row, and remove the 6th row? I guess I will have to play with this line and tried many combinations so far, but unsuccessfully:

```
open(file, 'w').writelines(lines[4:])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First you should get used to the slice notation in Python. Then you should know that you can join lists together with either the + operator or the "extend" method. So you can build a new list with desired lines and write it out at once.

Comment: The `fileinput` module has a convenient `inline` mode and gives you easy access to attributes like the current line number.